# How to customize download filename?

Tags: files

Drupal version: 7.14

Currently drupal save the downloaded filename as the last part of the URL, just like a file link "http://example.com/system/files/abc.txt", the default saved filename is "abc.txt".

I want to ask is how to change "abc.txt" to other filename such as "xyz.txt" while downloading.

Comment: Problem has been solved by setting download method to 'private', if it's set to 'public', you cannot do any control over the download process(that is hook_file_download cannot be called under this mode).

Comment: I looked into the function code and I think it'd be great if you could answer your own question and share your code to let others see what could be done by that hook. I bet you could earn some points too :)

Answer (score 2):

For this issue there's a prerequisite,that is, your download method must be 'private', otherwise there's no chance for drupal to call your 'hook_file_download', it's important!

Here's an example from drupal's file module, change $file->filename to what you want, then return to HTTP headers.

/**
 * Implements hook_file_download().
 *
 * This function takes an extra parameter $field_type so that it may
 * be re-used by other File-like modules, such as Image.
 */

> function file_file_download($uri, $field_type = 'file') {
>      global $user;
>      // Get the file record based on the URI. If not in the database just return.
>      $files = file_load_multiple(array(), array('uri' => $uri));
>      if (count($files)) {
>          foreach ($files as $item) {
>          // Since some database servers sometimes use a case-insensitive comparison
>          // by default, double check that the filename is an exact match.
>          if ($item->uri === $uri) {
>              $file = $item;
>              break;
>          }
>       }
>    }
>    if (!isset($file)) {
>      return;
>    }
>
> //...........................other codes.........................
>
> // Access specifically denied.
>    if ($denied) {
>      return -1;
>    }
>
> // Access is granted.
>    $headers = file_get_content_headers($file);
>    return $headers;
>   }

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7, when implementing Justin's solution, my download name was still the original filename, not the custom name I assigned to `$file->filename`. At the time of this writing Drupal 7's [file_get_content_headers()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_get_content_headers/7) sets

```
$name = mime_header_encode($file->filename);
```

but never uses the variable `$name`.

I found a few patches, but instead of patching core, I did the following:

```
$headers = file_get_content_headers($file);
$headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="'. $file->filename .'"';
return $headers;
```

For my purposes, I needed the file to be downloaded, which is why I used 'attachment'. But if you need the disposition to be 'inline', then the following snippet could get you started (copied from [this](https://drupal.org/files/issues/943112-1-file-headers.patch) patch):

```
$inline_types = variable_get('file_inline_types', array('^text/', '^image/', 'flash$'));
$disposition = 'attachment';
foreach ($inline_types as $inline_type) {
  // Exclamation marks are used as delimiters to avoid escaping slashes.
  if (preg_match('!' . $inline_type . '!', $file->filemime)) {
    $disposition = 'inline';
  }
}
```